# Ошибка в SQL SELECT запросе

Tags: mysqli

Есть вот такой код. По неизвестной мне причине запрос отвечает пустотой, а не количеством. Если group='ADMIN' заменить на другой столбец базы, то все работает. Возвращает количество.

```
$query_aa = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vip_overrides WHERE user_id='$vip_id' AND expires='0' AND group='ADMIN'";
$result_aa = mysqli_query($conn, $query_aa);
$row_aa = mysqli_fetch_row($result_aa);
$total_aa = $row_aa[0];
if(empty($total_aa)){$total_aa = "ww";}
echo $total_aa;
```

Comment: Пустота может быть только в случае ошибок в запросе. добавьте проверку на ошибки и выводите их, что бы понять, что происходит

Comment: Так может, прото, нет данных с таким набором условий

Comment: Если нет данных с таким набором, то должно возвращать 0, нет? Я же описал, если поменять столбец на другой, то он вполне адекватно возвращает 0, при отсутствии данных.